# R simple plotting issues

Tags: r

[image]I am trying to plot a line graph in R of Roll against time with RSudio.  The X and Y values are correct but the entire graph is Black

```
mru <- read.csv("E:/r-train/mru.txt", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
attach(mru)
plot( time, p1)

Time,r1,p1,h1,r2,p2,h2,r3,p3,h3
14:07:32,-0.08,0.41,0,-0.45,0.8145,1.4436,0.46,-0.06,0
14:07:33,-0.07,0.41,0,-0.459,0.8001,1.4436,0.46,-0.06,0
```

I also tried to format the time `mru <- read.csv("E/r-train/mru.txt", header = TRUE, sep = ",", format='%H:%M:%S')` and got the same result.

Also tried this: and it did not work

```
mru <- read.csv("E:/r-train/mru.txt", header = TRUE, sep = ",", as.is = TRUE)
mru[,1] <- as.POSIXct(strptime(mru[,1],"%H:%M:%S"))
plot(Time, h1)
```

Because it does this:

```
 $ Time: POSIXct, format: "2015-03-26 14:07:00" "2015-03-26 14:07:00" "2015-03-26 14:07:00" "2015-03-26 14:07:00" ...
 $ r1  : chr  "-0.08" "-0.07" "-0.07" "-0.07" ...
```

Comment: Why don't you supply what the first few lines of your dataframe look like. There's not much anyone can do to help you just knowing the name of your file

Comment: Please include a [minimum reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), otherwise it's nearly impossible for us to help.

Comment: In the example data you've included, `Time` is capitalized, whereas it isn't in your data. Also you should check the variable type of `time`. Try `plot(p1 ~ time, data=mru)` rather than attaching it.

Comment: The result is the same `Time` or `time` and `plot(p1 ~ time, data=mru)` nets the same result

Comment: The `read.csv` function is going to turn all the "Time" column into a factor variable. Look at `str(mru)` and learn NOT to use `attach()`. There is no "format"-parameter to `read.csv()` so that second call should have prompted an error message.

Comment: @BondedDust They are all factors after removing `attach()` how do I get them to `ints`?

Comment: You want to convert 'Time' to either a time or a data-time class and the others to "numeric". Converting factor to numeric (properly) is discussed in the R-FAQ. Converting to `POSIXct` is done with `strptime` and I think there is an `as.POSIXct.factor` method.